# My flutter property has not assign value in future block

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My flutter property has not changed in future blocks. I tried `setState(() {})` but not working.
I uninstalled flutterSdk and android SDK then I installed this SDK but still has not changed.
I had the same situation in my previous project. I copied the code of other pages and pasted it to the page that is not working. The page is working a little then page is wrong

this is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
class apiPage extends StatefulWidget {
const apiPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<apiPage> createState() => _apiPageState();
}

class _apiPageState extends State<apiPage> {
  String _response="exe";//this property is not working
Future <void> ApiCall() async{
   String adres="www.api";
   http.Response cevap=await http.get(Uri.parse(adres));
 if(cevap.statusCode==200){
     _response=cevap.body;//property needs to be changed

 }else{
   
     _response="error";//feature needs to be changed
 }

}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body:  ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
       Text('$_response'),

  ]
),

);
}
}
```

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I just want to assign data of api to response

Comment: why are you not using futurebuilder ?

Comment: How did you try to use `setState`?  Where did you call it?  Show the code where you tried using it.

Comment: where you are calling `ApiCall`

Answer (score 0):

When you like to update UI with new value, call `setState` on widget-state class. Here you can do,

```dart
if(cevap.statusCode==200){
   setState((){
    _response=cevap.body;
   });

 }else{
   setState((){
     _response="error";
   });    
 }
```

Make sure to call the `ApiCall()` method.

A better choice will be using `FutureBuilder` for future method. Find more about [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).